# ruby on rails heroku gem runtime error installing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is the error:[image]

I am getting an error while installing Heroku gem please help me.

What Should I Do?

Comment: Do you have the `heroku` CLI installed as mentioned in the error message? See: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli

Comment: yes i installed git and installed cli

Comment: How did you install the heroku CLI?

Comment: By running `gem install heroku` you're trying to install heroku via the ruby gem which is "no longer available" according to your error. Please run `heroku --version` in your console and paste the output here and also share your machine info.

Comment: Follow the instructions in your screen shot in bright red letters.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the official installation guide [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli).

You are installing ruby gem but what you need is `heroku-cli` which will help you run commands like, `heroku create`, `heroku push`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Actually It Worked , I Installed Heroku And Gone In Master Folder And It Worked Perfectly